# I have calculate and display result of trigonometric function on android app

Tags: android

When i click on digit button on app and then on cos for example, works fine.
When i click on cos and number, return -1.
For example on display TextView i see:
1cos
0.540302320
if i put:
cos1
-1

I use a switch case.

```
private double operateAritmetic(String a, String b, String op){
    switch (op){
        case "+": return (Double.valueOf(a) + Double.valueOf(b));
        case "-": return (Double.valueOf(a) - Double.valueOf(b));
        case "*": return (Double.valueOf(a) * Double.valueOf(b));
        case "/": try{
             return (Double.valueOf(a) / Double.valueOf(b));
        }catch (Exception e){Log.d("Calc",e.getMessage());
    }
   default: return -1;
    }
}

private double operateTrigonometric(String a, String op){
    switch (op){
        case "Sin":
            return(Math.sin(Double.valueOf(a)));
        case "Cos":
            return(Math.cos(Double.valueOf(a)));
        case "Tan":
            try{
            return(Math.tan(Double.valueOf(a)));
              }catch(Exception e){
                 Log.d("Calc", e.getMessage());
                }
        case "sqrt":
            return(Math.sqrt(Double.valueOf(a)));
        default: return -1;
    }
}

    public void onClickEqual(View v){
        String[] operation=display.split(Pattern.quote(currentOperator));
        Double result;
        if(operation.length==1) {
            result = operateTrigonometric(operation[0],currentOperator);
            _screen.setText(display + "\n" + String.valueOf(result));
        }

        else if (operation.length<2)
            return;

        else {
            result = operateAritmetic(operation[0], operation[1], currentOperator);
            _screen.setText(display + "\n" + String.valueOf(result));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try with same case sensitive text?

Comment: I tried to change the word sin etc.. in sin.., but don't change. I think is some problem with the function.